# What is the difference between UITableViewCell.classForCoder() and UITableViewCell.self when UITableView registers a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do swift get classes in OC I use [UITableViewCell class] in Swift?
Both pieces of code can run, but what's the difference?

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: UITableViewStyle.grouped)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")


let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: UITableViewStyle.grouped)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

Comment: Because of the literal **self** (explaining) operator.  Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the self property to refer to the current instance within its own instance methods.